# How can I get a SQL server job to restart itself?

Tags: sql-server

A little bit stuck on a problem we are having, let me try my best to explain the scenario, issues and what we have tried.

1. We have an SQL job which is logging to a specific file tagged with a date appended on to the end
2. The first step checks what our log file is e.g. log_01012012.log, if this is incorrect we updated the table sysjobsteps to have the new file location for all steps - e.g log_02012012.log. We are doing this by calling a stored proc in the first job step.
3. Whilst this gets updated in the table the remaining steps keep using the old log, due to what I'm assuming is that this table only gets read once when the job is started.

We have tried to restart the job within the stored proc with the following code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name = 'My Job'
waitfor delay '00:00:15'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'My Job'
```

However, when we kill the job it appears as it kills the stored procedure (which i guess is a child of the job) which means it never gets to the step to restart the job.

Is there a way in which a job can restart itself so it looks at the sysjobsteps table again and uses the correct location for the logging?

Things which might solve the issue would be

- Being able to restart a job from the job itself
- Being able to refresh the job in some respect.

Anything I need to clarify I will do my best but we are currently stuck and all input will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

go to sql server agent on SSMS

expand Jobs

1. create a job,
2. define the steps (sp or simple query)
3. define the schedule (how often or even start the job when the sqlserver restarts)
4. set notification to email you when job completes ( succeeded/failed )

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Rhian, we don't need to run the job on a regular schedule, it is the first step which checks a condition and if met updates the sysjobsteps table which then means we have to restart it for the remaining steps to take the new values

Answer (score 0):

You could do something fancy with Service Broker.  Something like:

1) Put a message into a broker queue as the last step of your job. The content can be empty; it's just a token to say "hey... the job needs to be resubmitted".

2) Write an activation stored procedure for the queue that puts in a delay (like you're doing in your already existing procedure) and then resubmit the job

Or, you instead of hardcoding the log file name in the job steps themselves, put that data in a table somewhere. Then, in your step that changes the location define the success condition as "go to next step" and the failure condition as "go to step 1".  Then modify the code that changes the file location to return an error (thus triggering the job step's failure condition).

Answer (score 0):

Realise nearly a decade old, but I had the same problem and solved it as follows.  Using the code that the OP suggested:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'My Job A'
```

Simply create a matching pair of Jobs, each of which has an identical first step (doing the actual work) and a final step containing the above code but pointing at the opposite job name (basically you can't restart the same job from itself as far as I can tell).  Just make sure you set the Step Behaviour in the Advanced tab to execute this final step in each case and the job will just rumble away indefinitely.